# When to use a lockstep protocol?

Tags: networking, multiplayer

What types of games benefit most from lockstep? What games are not suitable for a lockstep protocol? What are the disadvantages of lockstep?

Comment: This question is a bit broad to answer definitively for all games, since different games will use different mixes of techniques for many varied reasons. If you're weighing applying lockstep in your current game project, you're likely to get better answers by focusing on your game's needs. What features are you implementing, what problems are you facing that you think lockstep might solve, or what problems are you facing implementing lockstep that you need to find solutions or alternatives for? This narrows the question to a scope where we can evaluate correct, working solutions to the problem.

Comment: By using lockstep, I am thinking my game will always be in sync across clients. the state of the game will always be 100% accurate across clients for everyone. My game is an action game but it's not that fast-paced.

Comment: Sounds good. Is there anything specific holding you back?

Comment: I don't want to spend time implementing a system that may not be optimal for my game. It doesn't seem like the system sees much use outside RTS games yet it seems like the perfect networking model to me so I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: StackExchange is better at troubleshooting a specific problem than at acting as a crystal ball to forecast what might go wrong in the future. If the techniques you're thinking of sound good to you, and you can't think of any specific problem with them, then I'd say it's at least worth prototyping to see if they hold up in practice.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking what aspects of a game would make implementing a lockstep ideal. There's tons of games out there and tons of genre, yet the amount of them that use lockstep is rather small I believe so there must be something about lockstep that makes it un-ideal for certain types of games or games with certain properties. What are they?